# $A$ and $B$ are connected subsets in a metric space X. Prove at least one of $ A\cup B $ or $ A\cap B $ is connected.

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

> $A$ and $B$ are connected subsets in a metric space X. Prove at least one of $ A\cup B $ or $ A\cap B $ is connected.

I'm not sure where to start for this one. All I know about multiple connected sets is that if $ A\cap B \not = \phi $ then $ A\cup B $ is connected.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: "orc"?${}{}{}{}$ (If you meant "or $A\cap B$", note the empty set is connected.)

Comment: Sorry, typo! Thank you!

Comment: For the purposes of this question it seems necessary to take $\emptyset$ to be connected.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Yes, a space is [connected iff it is not the union of two disjoint *nonempty* open sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectedness).

Answer (score 2):

If $A\cap B$ is disconnected, then it has at least two points, so it's non empty. Then $A\cup B$ is connected.

---

A subset $C$ of a topological space (metric space if this is your topic) $X$ is disconnected if there are open sets $U$ and $V$ such that
$$
C=(U\cap C)\cup(V\cap C)
\quad\text{and}\quad
(U\cap C)\cap(V\cap C)=\emptyset
$$
with both $U\cap C$ and $V\cap C$ non empty.

In particular, the empty set is connected.